# Dynamic Expression in StimulSoft Reports

Tags: c#, wpf, report, stimulsoft

I have this price column in my Report that depends on other columns value for example if HasLoan column be true and IsSale column be true then price columns value should be

> "Price:{Consigner.LoanAmount}, Loan:{Consigner.SellPrice}"

The LoanAmount and SellPrice columns are seprate columns.
I have already wrote this but it doesn't work and throws Exception:

```
{({Consigner.HasLoan} == true) ? "Loan:"+{Consigner.LoanAmount}:""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use braces in the expression

```
{(Consigner.HasLoan == true) ? "Loan:"+Consigner.LoanAmount:""}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it in stimulsoft:

```
{IIF(Consigner.HasLoan,"Loan: " Consigner.LoanAmount ,"")}
```